# NodeJS WebSocket serve using only 'http' - Node documentation example doesn't work

Tags: node.js, websocket, browser, server

Specifically the example doesn't work while trying to connect to the server from a browser.

I'm trying to understand how websockets work by building my "own" toy server on top of the 'http' node stdlib - I am specifically uninterested in using 'ws' or 'socket.io'. As far as I can tell, it should be very straightforward, using the example out of https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-upgrade this *should* be able to work:

```
const srv = createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
  res.end("okay");
});
srv.on("upgrade", (req, socket, head) => {
  socket.write(
    "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" +
      "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" +
      "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
      "\r\n"
  );

  socket.pipe(socket); // echo back
});

// Now that server is running
srv.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

And indeed on the server side I can see the upgrade attempts - but in both Chrome and Firefox, when I attempt to call

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1337");
```

I get either `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:1337/.` or `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1337' failed` respectively, with no further clarifying information. Interestingly, the network tab does not actually show network information being transferred in either direction, merely labeling the connection as "failed". The addition of the header

```
    `Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ${createHash("sha1")
      .update(acceptKey + "258EAFA5-E914–47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", "binary")
      .digest("base64")}`,
```

also did not help.

I am able to reproduce what feels like the correct behavior simply via netcat, by running

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 1337
GET /api/foo/simpleStream HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:80
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Accept: */*
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://example.com:80
Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Sat, 20 Aug 2022 22:43:30 GMT
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: Tx+xOvGxLDsNsmVI6vW1uIyc/jQ=

this will echo
this will echo
```

This to me points at an issue where browsers are expecting websocket connections to behave a bit different from what I am interpretting it as - does anyone know what might be going on here, or have pointers to documentation that I am missing?

Comment: What you did so far is a pretty basic start to the Websocket handshake. Websockets have their own protocol/framing and you need to send back the correct header. It's not like a regular socket where you can just send data over the wire.

Comment: If you plan to write a new implementation (would love to see a better one than `ws`!), you need to start by reading the full RFC: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455

Comment: While it does look like I have a bit more reading to do with regards to how dataframes are exchanged over the TCP connection, it looks like the issue was in the magic string used for computing the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header - I had it as `258EAFA5-E914–47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11`, where that second hyphen is actually an en-dash and so bitwise distinct from the correct magic string of `258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11`. Pretty angry at whichever site I copied that code from...

Answer (score 0):

While it does look like I have a bit more reading to do with regards to how dataframes are exchanged over the TCP connection, it looks like the issue was in the magic string used for computing the Sec-WebSocket-Accept header - I had it as `258EAFA5-E914–47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11`, where that second hyphen is actually an en-dash and so bitwise distinct from the correct magic string of `258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11`.

For what it is worth, a minimal implementation of a WebSocket handshake from the server's perspective is:

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import { createHash } from "crypto";

const srv = createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
  res.end("okay");
});

function websocketResponse(acceptKey: string) {
  return [
    "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols",
    "Upgrade: websocket",
    `Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ${createHash("sha1")
      .update(acceptKey + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
      .digest("base64")}`,
    "Connection: Upgrade",
    "\r\n",
  ].join("\r\n");
}
srv.on("upgrade", (req, socket, head) => {
  const headers = websocketResponse(req.headers["sec-websocket-key"]);

  socket.write(headers);
  console.log("upgrading", headers);
});

srv.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: And, a full minimal implementation of a websocket server in TS with no dependencies: https://gist.github.com/digitaltembo/10d2df56ce1843ac468f8b6306149b0b